# Converting a DOS Application to a Win32 Console Application?

Tags: windows, dos

Is it possible to convert a DOS Application to a Win32 Console Application? I have an old program I wrote a long time ago, lost the source to it and asked myself now if it's possible to convert the DOS Binary to an actual Windows Binary, which runs in Command Line Prompt?

Comment: if you want to run a program under dos in windows enviroment you can use DOSBox0.74 , i use it to run old games under dos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The DOS program will attempt to use DOS system calls that do not exist under Windows. The program will need to be updated and rebuilt for Windows. You might have some success running the original program in a DOS emulator.

Comment: It's incorrect that the program has to be rebuilt for Windows to run it. DOSBox, WineVDM (for 64-bit Windows) and NTVDM (for 32-bit Windows, built in to Windows) are all able to run DOS programs, and there are many other emulators.

Comment: @pts This answer specifically mentions the option of using an emulator to run the original program.

Comment: @RossRidge the answer could use some editing/restructuring to make it clear at first sight. Also saying it's not possible, then saying it is possible contradicts itself.

Answer (score 1):

See other answers about running a DOS program under Windows.

To convert a DOS program to a Win32 console application, one would have to convert the 16-bit (8086) code within the DOS program to 32-bit (i386) code. This is a very hard task to do right, and probably that's why there is no converter readily available. (Alternatively, an emulator can run 16-bit code without conversion, see the other answers and comments.)

However, not all DOS programs contain 16-bit code, for example programs using DOS extenders built with the Watcom C/C++ compiler (or, equivalently, with OpenWatcom: `owcc -bdos4g prog.c`) contain only 32-bit code. Windows can run 32-bit code directly, but API calls (e.g. opening and reading a file, allocating memory, getting the current time, writing colorful text to the console) have to be converted from the DOS+DPMI API to the Win32 API. Such a conversion is technically possible and feasible (even on the final .exe file, without access to the source code), and it is much easier to do correctly than the conversion of 16-bit code to 32-bit code. However, I still don't know of a converter readily available.

Please also note that conversion graphics and audio code to the Win32 API is very hard, but that's out of scope in this question.